# npm install command gets failed in my machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

I have tried to run the npm install command, but it gets failed continuously. I have tried by installing the latest version 8.9.3 but the same issue occurs.

node version: 8.9.3
npm version: 4.6.1

Error:

[image]

Can you please suggest how to clear this issue?

Comment: You need to have package.json file in the pwd where you are running the command

Comment: are you running the command on windows command prompt?

Comment: I have run it from windows command prompt only from the root folder which contains package.json file

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10897 and see if anything on there helps. It looks like it's an issue with expired certificate

Comment: @user184994, we followed the same steps npm set registry <link> but while running this command, nothing works..